# fetch first record form database in java?

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

I have created a java class and I want to fetch the first record from the database I am using the query to fetch it but it is not working and gives some Exception.

using this code :

```
else if(ae.getSource()==btnfirst)
{   
    try{        
            m.rs=m.st.executeQuery("Select * from purchase ");
            m.rs.first();

                inv=m.rs.getInt(1);
                String inv1=Integer.toString(inv);

                int qty2=m.rs.getInt(5);
                String qty1=Integer.toString(qty2);

                rate=m.rs.getInt(6);
                String rate1=Integer.toString(rate);

                txtinvoice1.setText(inv1);
                txtdate1.setText(m.rs.getString(2));
                txtparty1.setText(m.rs.getString(3));
                ctrucktype1.setSelectedItem(m.rs.getString(4));
                txtcalu1.setText(qty1);
                txtrate1.setText(rate1);
                txtbuilty1.setText(m.rs.getString(7));

    }catch(Exception e)
        {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

after using **limit 1** stack trace gives

```
H:\Workspace\Mining Inventory\Project\src>java mdiform
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in
 FROM clause.
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6956)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7113)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLExecDirect(JdbcOdbc.java:3109)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.execute(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:337)
        at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcOdbcStatement.java:2
52)
        at PurchaseMaster.actionPerformed(PurchaseMaster.java:307)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:20
18)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.jav
a:2341)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel
.java:402)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259
)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonL
istener.java:252)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6504)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6269)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4860)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832
)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)

        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2713)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4686)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:707)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:76)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:87)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:680)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:678)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDo
main.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:677)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:211)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.
java:128)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThre
ad.java:117)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:113)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:105)

        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: *What* exception does it give? It's in the stacktrace, please show us.

Comment: `Select * from purchase LIMIT 1`

Comment: There's no guarantee which record you'll get even after you've solved your exception. You need an ORDER BY in your query if you are concerned about that.

Comment: LIMIT keyword is DBMS specific. It is supported by MySQL but Oracle.

Comment: Take the LIMIT clause off and post the original exception - it was broken before you started putting the LIMIT clause on, but we have no evidence of what that problem was.

Answer (score 2):

If you need only first record your query should be:

```
Select * from purchase LIMIT 1
```

You should ask from database more then you need because it takes time for result to come to you.

**EDIT:** As you probably using `Oracle`, you should try this:

```
SELECT * FROM purchase WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Also you need something specific in `WHERE` because limitation helps you to get only one result but it is very unlikely to get result you want if you do not specify any conditions.

Comment: LIMIT keyword is DBMS specific. It is supported by MySQL but not Oracle.

Comment: Most DBMS provide some method of limiting returned rows. For example, MySQL uses LIMIT, T-SQL uses TOP, Oracle uses ROWNUM. Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are missing an rs.next() statement, but it's hard to tell without seeing the exception. `rs.first` will throw an exception if it's used on a result set that is `TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`. I believe that this is the default.

```
try{        
            m.rs=m.st.executeQuery("Select * from purchase ");
 ***           m.rs.next();  ***

                inv=m.rs.getInt(1);
                String inv1=Integer.toString(inv);

                int qty2=m.rs.getInt(5);
```

Comment: not really, there's a rs.first() call which will position the ResultSet as the first row.

Comment: It will providing the result set has been set up correctly. Otherwise it'll throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

As you require only first record, it's meaningless to fetch all records from database and retrieve first record out of it. I would suggest you to limit records selected based on default order.

```
Select * from purchase order by purchase_date LIMIT 1
```